# Given a 10^8 rows, 10GB import, is it better to import data on separate rows or consolidate and separate the rows in the DB?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, database-performance

I'm doing a rather large import to a SQL Database, 10^8+ items and I am doing this with a bulk insert.  I'm curious to know if the speed at which the bulk insert runs can be improved by importing multiple rows of data as a single row and splitting them once imported?

If the time to import data is defined by the sheer volume of data itself (ie. 10GB), then I'd expect that importing 10^6 rows vs 10^2 with the data consolidated would take about the same amount of time.

If the time to import however is limited more by row operations and logging each line and not by the data itself then I'd expect that consolidating data would have a performance benefit.  I'm not sure however how this would carry over if one had tot then break up the data in DB later on.

Does anyone have experience with this and can shed some light on what specifically can be done to reduce bulk insert time without simply adding that time later to split the data in DB?

Given a 10GB import, is it better to import data on separate rows or consolidate and separate the rows in the DB?

[EDIT] I'm testing this on a Quad 2.5GH with 8GB or RAM and 300MB/sec of read/writes to disk (stripped array). The files are hosted n the same array and the average row size varies with some rows containing large amounts of data (> 100 KB) and many under 100 B.

I've chunked my data into 100 MB files and it takes about 40 seconds to import the file.  Each file has 10^6 rows in it.

Comment: Even the slowest possible 10GB import will probably have finished in less time than it took to write this question. Just saying. :-)

Comment: Given that your rows are about 100 bytes each, there's unlikely to be any gain from batching then bursting the rows.  And as Aaron says, a 10GB shouldn't normally be that slow.  How long is this taking and what's the HW configuration like?

Answer (score 2):

Where is the data that you are importing?  If it is on **another server**, then the Network might be the bottleneck.  This then depends on number of NIC'S and frame sizes.

If it is on the **same server**, things to play with are batch size and recovery model which effect the log file.  In full recovery model, everything is written to a log file.  Bulk copy recovery model is a little less overhead in the log.

Since this is staging data, maybe a full backup before the process, change the model to simple, then import might reduce the time.  Of course, change the model back to full and do another backup.

As for importing non-normalized data, multiple rows at a time, I usually stay away from the extra coding.

Most of the time, I use SSIS packages.  More packages, threads, means a fuller NIC pipe.  I usually have at least a 4 GB back bone that is seldom full.

Other things that come to play are your disks.  Do you have multiple files (path ways) to the RAID 5 array?  If not, you might want to think about it.

In short, it really depends on your environment.

Use a DMAIC process.

```
1 - Define what you want to do
2 - Measure the current implementation
3 - Analyze ways to improve.
4 - Implement the change.
5 - Control the environment by remeasuring.  

    Did the change go in the positive direction?
    If not, rollback the change and try another one.
```

Repeat the process until the desired result (timing) is achieve.

Good luck, J

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time thing and done in an offline change window.. you may want to consider to put the database in simple recovery model prior to inserting the data.

Keep in mind though this would break the log chain....